# IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`),numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices at clustering graphic

Tags: graphics, cluster-analysis, k-means

Please, does someone know why I have
"only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices"  error when I run this?

```
fig = plt.figure (figsize = (6,6)) 
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1) 
ax.set_xlabel('Componente 1', fontsize =15) 
ax.set_ylabel('Componente 2', fontsize = 15) 
ax.set_title('Componentes Principales', fontsize = 20)

color_theme = np.array(["blue","green","orange","red"]) 
ax.scatter(x = DATAPCA.Componente_1, y = DATAPCA.Componente_2, c= color_theme[DATAPCA.PERFIL], s = 50)
```

I am trying to plot a graphic for Kmeans clustering